# How can I change a valve that leaks at the joint?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I have a valve in a box in the ground. It has a very small leak at the joint between the tube and the tap itself. I tried to tighten a little bit but it didn’t help.

I think the only option that I see is remove it entirely, apply new sealant special for tubes (white strip) and put it back.

However, I am wondering how hard it is. Also, am I at risk of the tube underneath being damaged, and not being able to put it back?

[image]

Comment: Those are normally ball valves (a tap allows water out of the system)  , with the compression fittings I haven’t seen anything other than cutting that really works on that tubing but being in the ground you really don’t have that option. With no room to work with if I would decide if it needs to be fixed, I have only used that type of pipe on irrigation / drip systems.

Comment: Be aware that "sealant" isn't really a thing in plumbing. With the exception of thread compound on threaded steel or iron pipe, all other joints are made with gaskets, o-rings, copper soldering, compression rings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the main shut off for the water supply from the street to the house you will have to contact the water department to have them shut off the water supply at the street before you remove that valve or proceed with any repair.

The orange handle is for a quarter-turn valve that shuts off the supply. Those serrated nuts on either end of that valve are for removing that valve. That big part on the right side may be a union nut. The other joints may be threaded or glued (can't tell from the picture). Also, I do not see the white strip you are referencing.

Before you try any repair you need to know just what that valve is for and how to turn off the water supply to it if necessary. If you shut off that valve any down stream repair can be made and the fittings removed but not on the supply side without shutting off the water supply. I hope this helps.